# Inserting PHP variable into Html5 "Placeholder" attribute

Tags: php, html, placeholder

I tried the following, and it shows an empty text area, the value isn't displayed:

```
    <input type="textarea" class="class1" name="name1" placeholder="<?= $val1?>" />
```

Any thoughts on what should be done so it will work?

Update: It is now working, the value was empty, therefore text area didn't show anything. The code can be used safely.

Comment: Is PHP `short_open_tag` enabled? What does the page source look like after you render it?

Comment: "it didn't work". In what way didn't it work? Was the value present in the rendered HTML? Were there any PHP
 error messages?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "didn't work". Is there an error on the page? Is the html attribute empty? Are you sure that `$val1` contains a value?

Comment: @Asaph - thanks! the value was indeed empty. It is now showing the value

Comment: @michael yes, short tag is enabled and it is working otherwise and with it, thanks

Comment: can someone please explain why all the downvotes? it is perfectly healthy code, even working now, wtf?

Comment: try choosing an answer if it was helpfull. Zulkhaery Basrul seems to mention the answer by _if $val1 is not null ..._ :)

Comment: the answer is actually in the comments here by @Asaph

Comment: the answer you are talking about it all about short tags, and that is certainly not the answer in this case

Comment: @Lucy Weatherford: I've added an answer that is the same as my comment. Please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `$val1` actually contains a non-empty value. If it does, your code should create a non-empty `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="textarea" class="class1" name="name1" placeholder="<?php echo $val1; ?>" />
```

There is no such input `type` attribute as `textarea`.

Do you mean:

```
<textarea class="class1" name="name1" placeholder="<?php echo $val1; ?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: `textarea` is not a valid value for the `type` property of the `input` tag.

Comment: Probably because before @Phoenix's edit, your answer didn't really read like an answer.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine with `<input type="textarea"`

Answer (score 3):

if `$val1` is not null, i think the problem is short tag (`<?= ?>`).

You can override this config, at the top of file, put this line to enable short tag:

```
ini_set('short_open_tag',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the variable is empty (as @Asaph suggested in his comment).
Entered a value and now it is working just fine.